# Отрисовка компонента

Tags: reactjs

Пример кода

```
import React from 'react'

const PossibilitiesCaution = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <li className="uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-grid-margin" style={{minHeight: '119px'}} data-uk-scrollspy={{cls:'uk-animation-slide-right', delay:'250'}}>
                <h4 style={{fontSize:'22px', lineHeight:'30px', fontWeight:'400',margin:'30px 0 15px'}}>SOS</h4>
                <p className="uk-text-muted"><i className="uk-text-large"></i></p>
                <p className="uk-text-muted">
                    Тревожная кнопка - поддержка водителя в чрезвычайных ситуациях
                </p>
           </li>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

export {PossibilitiesCaution}
```

Это один из 6 блоков, которые мне нужно отрисовать. Я не хочу для каждого блока делать отдельный компонент, но не могу понять как из:

```
<i className="uk-icon-minus-circle...>
```

достать глификон. Брать заголовок для блока и описание блока из json не проблема, а что делать с иконками, которых там 6 штук( по одной на блок). Все глификоны задаются через css.

Comment: `Я не хочу для каждого блока делать отдельный компонент` сделайте один, и передавайте ему glyphIcon="iconstyle". А в компоненте подставляйте this.props.glyphIcon

Comment: `this.props` - это в в компонентах которые через класс созданы, сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через пропсы конечно

```
const Example = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h1>Here is your icon</h1>
        <i className={ props.iconClass } />
    </div>
);
```

Передаете в компонент

```
<Example iconClass="uk-icon-minus-circle" />
```

Comment: Я относительно недавно этим занимаюсь и не совсем понимаю, о чем вы. Но буду пробовать.

Comment: @IvanIvan Это пропсы которые ты можешь передать в компонент, передаешь как атрибут  
`<Example some="text" another="data"  />`, внутри компонента получаешь это значение как `props.some === "text"`, `props.another === "data"`